# SymPy cannot calculate cardioid length (Integrate Problem)

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

SymPy cannot calculate the length of the cardioid.
How to write the code to calculate the length of a closed line?
Python 3.7.1 SymPy 1.3

```
from sympy import *
fi = symbols('fi')
cont = integrate(sqrt((1+sin(fi))**2+(cos(fi))**2), (fi, -pi/2, pi/2))
print(cont)
>>>
Integral(sqrt((sin(fi) + 1)**2 + cos(fi)**2), (fi, -pi/2, pi/2))
```

Comment: An unevaluated `Integral` means SymPy's algorithms don't know how to compute the integral.

Comment: I understand that SymPy cannot calculate it. I would like to know how it can be calculated in another way?

Comment: Achieving symbolic integration with Sympy (or also with Maple or Mathematica) always needs a bit of luck, because there exist no universal algorithms for it. Wolfram Alpha happens know the integral: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5B(1%2BSin%5Bx%5D)%5E2+%2B+Cos%5Bx%5D%5E2%5D,x%5D https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5B(1%2BSin%5Bx%5D)%5E2+%2B+Cos%5Bx%5D%5E2%5D,%7Bx,+-pi%2F2,+pi%2F2%7D%5D

Answer (score 1):

- ***Get a numerical result of this integral*** :

Have you tried **`evalf`** ? (https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/evalf.html)

Just call it like this :

`integrate(sqrt((1+sin(fi))**2+(cos(fi))**2), (fi, -pi/2, pi/2)).evalf()`.

It returns the value of this integral :
**`4.0`**

- ***Check this result by hand*** :
  As you asked if it can be calculted another way, I give some steps to calculate it.
  Let's first transform the radicand expression :

[image: trigfact]

Now, using the follwing identity :

[image: trigfact]

will drive us to this expression :
[image: trigfact]

So the integral can be written as well :

[image: integral]

which can be computed easily, and gives us the expected result.